# Self-Reference One-to-One mapping in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, one-to-one, self-reference

I have a class A which has a property type indicating whether it is a receipt or a delivery. A receipt can be mapped to a single delivery and vice-versa. Now consider that the receipt transaction and the delivery transaction are siblings.
So class A has a *sibling* of type A. "A" and its sibling have a *one-to-one* relationship as established above.

```
Class A {  
    private A sibling;  
}

<hibernate-mapping>  
    <class name="A" table="A">  
        <id name="Id" type="java.lang.Integer" column="id">  
            <generator class="native"></generator>  
        </id>  
        <one-to-one  name="sibling" class="A" lazy="proxy" />  
    </class>  
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I am unable to figure out a way to create a self-referencing one-to-one mapping.

Comment: what does the bean look like please

Answer (score 2):

Use the `many-to-one` unidirectional association. See [Unidirectional associations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/associations.html#assoc-unidirectional-join) in the hibernate reference documentation.

```
<hibernate-mapping>   
    <class name="A" table="A">   
        <id name="Id" type="java.lang.Integer" column="id">   
            <generator class="native"></generator>   
        </id>   
        <many-to-one  name="sibling" class="A" cascade="all" />   
    </class>   
</hibernate-mapping>
```

You can read those answers for more information on

- [Why use many-to-one to represent a one-to-one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452987/hibernate-why-use-many-to-one-to-represent-a-one-to-one)
- [How to stop Hibernate from eagerly fetching many-to-one associated object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222453/how-to-stop-hibernate-from-eagerly-fetching-many-to-one-associated-object)