# Hibernate criteria return more than one class

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I am newbie to Hibernate criteria and I got problem with simple obtain class.
Assume we have classes:

```
    Class A{
    int id;
    List<A> aList;
    }
```

and:

```
  Class B{
    A a;
    (...)

}
```

and :

```
Class C{
int id;
String name;
B b;
}
```

I want to get List< C > if 'name' like 'abc'. Here is my criteria code:

```
    Session session = hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(C.class);
    crit.add(Restrictions.like("nazwa", "%"+string+"%").ignoreCase());
    return crit.list();
```

I got exception:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist:
>   character varying = integer

In my SQL query generated by criteria I can see "left outer join" on my A and B classes that are contained in my C class. Probably that's why I cannot load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be left outer joins if the associations are `@OneToOne` or `@ManyToOne`, just because they are eager in the *ToOne* owning side by default.

If you want to use such a `LIKE` clause, use [`MatchMode.ANYWHERE`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.2/api/org/hibernate/criterion/MatchMode.html#ANYWHERE)  and [`ilike`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#ilike%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.hibernate.criterion.MatchMode%29) instead:

```
add(Restrictions.ilike("nazwa", string, MatchMode.ANYWHERE))
```

Also, make sure the property you want to query in class `C` is named `nazwa` (it is typed as `name` in the code example), and it has a proper getter/setter.

Comment: yes, there are @ManyToOne annotations. How to drop left outer join in this criteria? I must select only my C class...

Comment: You can find the answer to that question in this site easily: [How to stop Hibernate from eagerly fetching many-to-one associated object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/222453/851811). Have you tried `@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)` ?